# how to make button with image responsive

Tags: html, css

The background is responsive as well, but the button with image and the marquee don't appear on their right position via on mobile,
how to make the the whole index responsive

```
      <div class="main">
        <div class="marquee">
          <marquee dir="ltr" direction="right" scrollamount="3">
            <h3 style="color:#804000;font-size:large;margin-top:0px;" align="center" >       
             <strong>  
              <img src="http://www.ghadaalsamman.com/new/images/image21.png" height="37" />
            </strong>
           </h3>
         </marquee>
       </div>
     </div>
      <a href="http://ghadaalsamman.com/new/site.html" id="btn1" class="button"></a>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: url('images/bg.gif'); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;
}
.marquee{
    position:absolute;
    left:400px;
    top:300px;
    right:400px;
    display:inline;
    max-width:100%;
}
#btn1 {
    height:60px; width:490px;
    background: url("images/enter.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top:610px;
    margin-left:380px;
}
.button {
    padding: 5px;
 }
```

**Fiddle :**

**http://jsfiddle.net/m0sagal/3fp9j/**

**Desktop View**

http://ghadaalsamman.com/new

Comment: fiddle please .... and responsive image

Comment: [link](http://www.ghadaalsamman.com/new) check the whole website

Comment: Give the button a position please

Comment: i gave it fixed position , and got the same result:(

Comment: You can use @media queries to make this easy

Comment: can you give me the code , i tried with no luck

Comment: Your code is very messed up, I need a fiddle to play with.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m0sagal/3fp9j/
and here's the desktop view
http://www.ghadaalsamman.com/new/

Comment: @MahmoudElkholly : you are coding in `px`, how do you expect layout to be *responsive* ....since you are not even using media queries?? :)

Comment: well , i'm NOOB too :D can you edit the code for me?

Comment: @MahmoudElkholly : what do you mean by `don't appear on their right position` ....you want `anchor` tag to be right align?

Comment: when i open the website on mobile , the button doesn't appear on its RIGHT position

Comment: you have added `margin-left : 380px`....it must be appearing but in the extreme right...open the site and go on sliding to the left, i ma sure you'll find it there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Imran_Bughio/b7FTY/4/)*

I have made some changes in html & css so use this code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="marquee">
            <marquee scrollamount="3" direction="right" dir="ltr">
                 <h3 align="center" style="color:#804000;font-size:large;margin-top:0px;"><strong>  
    <img height="37" src="http://www.ghadaalsamman.com/new/images/image21.png">
        </strong></h3>

            </marquee>
        </div>
<a class="button" id="btn1" href="http://ghadaalsamman.com/new/site.html"></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    background-image: url("http://www.ghadaalsamman.com/new/images/bg.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.marquee {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 43%;
    width: 100%;
}
#btn1 {
    background-image: url("http://www.ghadaalsamman.com/new/images/enter.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
    height: 53px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.button {
    padding: 5px;
}
.container {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px;
    position: relative;
}
.main {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
@media screen and (max-width:500px) {
    #btn1{
        background-size: 100% auto;
    }
}
```

**What i did:**

I added a div after main named container & used it to control max with and fitted both marquee and button inside it using absolute position & that's pretty much did all the trick but for the button background image i have used media query.

Comment: overflow over what? the container with maxWidth ?

Comment: Thanks man , but the marquee doesn't appear on it's right postion

Comment: @ImranBughio : what you did, can be done without media query...let me post my solution..wait!

Comment: @NoobEditor would love to see a non media query solution for the button :)

Comment: @ImranBughio : the marquee is appear on the top of page not in it's place as the desktop view:(

Comment: Check **[Revisoun #4](http://jsfiddle.net/Imran_Bughio/b7FTY/4/)** of demo may be this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I am leaving for breakfast.. best of luck Mahmoud Elkholly -- BTW you should start by learning basic of css -- we are here to help you if you get stuck in a problem, & not to make entire page responsive for you - cheers.

Comment: any suggested tuts for MediaQuery?

Comment: thanks man , i have a problem the website doesn't work on IE :(

Comment: hello guys please help me out

Comment: Hi, the syntax in which background image is defined in `body` & `#btn1` is not understood by IE - check background property in my updated answer -- let me know if this helped.

Comment: You have accepted NoobEditor answer? -- even thou the button is all stretched out in his fiddle?

Comment: i tried your latest update and it doesn't work on the mobile IE

Comment: hmm not sure about IE mobile, solution i gave was for IE8

Comment: it's appear as a blank page